# Is radial projection of positive measure set also positive measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a set of positive Lebesgue measure. Is it true that the set
$$\{\|x\|:x\in A\}\subset [0,\infty)$$
also a set of positive Lebesgue measure in  $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: Yes. I think it's easiest to prove this by contradiction/contrapositive: show that if if the set $\{\|x\| : x \in A\} \subset [0,\infty)$ has measure zero, then $A$ must have measure zero.

Comment: See polar coordinates in $\mathbb R^{n}$ in Rudin's RCA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a set of positive Lebesgue measure. Then $B = A \setminus \{0\} \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is also  set of positive Lebesgue measure.

Now, using polar coordinates in $\Bbb R ^n$, we have that there is a function $f: \Bbb R ^+ \times S^{n-1} \to \Bbb R$  such that  $f(r, \omega) = \mathbf{1}_B(r\omega)$.

Then, using Tonelli's theorem,
$$ \lambda (A) = \lambda (B) = \int_{\Bbb R^n} \mathbf{1}_B d \lambda = \int_{S^{n-1}} \left (\int_{\Bbb R^+} f(r , \omega) d r \right ) d \omega \leq \int_{S^{n-1}} \lambda (\{\|x\|:x\in B\}) d\omega. \tag{1}$$

If $\lambda(\{\|x\|:x\in A\})=0$, then, since $B \subseteq A$, we have  $\lambda (\{\|x\|:x\in B\})=0$, and then, from $(1)$, we have $\lambda (A) = 0$.

So, if $\lambda (A) \ne 0$, then $\lambda(\{\|x\|:x\in A\}) \ne 0$. $\square$